# MVC Post Action method not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently working on inserting records functionality of MVC 5 application. For some reason the post action method doesn't fire. I am created an button on View that should trigger the post action method. Not sure why it is not firing. The form elements are in partial view and the button control is not the main view that host the partial view.

Here is the code

**Main view**

```
@model CC.GRP.MCRequest.ViewModels.NewRequestViewModel


<div class="newrequest">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Request/RequestHeaderView.cshtml");
</div>


<div id="buttonalign" class="buttonalign" >
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Request_Insert", "Request")'" >Save as draft</button>

 </div>
```

**Request Header View**

```
@model CC.GRP.MCRequest.ViewModels.NewRequestViewModel
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

    <div id="NewRequest">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RequestID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RequestID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:100%", @readonly = "readonly" } })

                        </div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RequestID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.Name1)

                 .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
                .DataTextField("Name1")
                .DataValueField("CustomerMasterDataId")

                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Read(read => read.Action("RequestHeader_CustomerData", "Request").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
                )
                  .Events(e =>
                  {
                      e.Change("onCustomerComboChange");
                  })
                            )
                        </div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:100%", @readonly = "readonly" } })

                        </div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**Request Controller**

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Request_Insert(NewRequestViewModel userVM)
        {
            NewRequestViewModel newReqeustViewModel = new NewRequestViewModel();
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return null;
            }
            requestRepository.CreateRequest(Mapper.Map<Request>(userVM));
            //return Json(requestRepository.CreateRequest(userVM));
            return View("NewRequestView", newReqeustViewModel);
        }
```

Comment: You don't have a submit button, and the buttons you _do_ have are not part of the form. Are you aware of how forms work?

Comment: I have changed the button to type submit. And enclosed contents of the Main view in form element. It still dint work

Comment: Can you update your code to reflect the change you've made now?  What is currently here definitely won't work because, as Tieson T. said your submit button isn't enclosed in your form.

Comment: `Html.BeginForm()` generates an HTML `<form>` element. You don't want to have a form inside of a form (that would be invalid), and if the buttons are inside a different form, it won't submit the other form.

Comment: You _could_ use the [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-form) attribute on your submit button, if you _have_ to have this layout

Comment: So are you saying remove the html.beginform in the request header view and enclose the contents of the main view in form element. I just tried that and it dosent fire. If it is incorrect could you give me an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should put

```
<div id="buttonalign" class="buttonalign" >
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Request_Insert", "Request")'" >Save as draft</button>

 </div>
```

inside

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Request_Insert", "Request", FormMethod.Post))
    {
}
```

in **Request Header View**

and 
update

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

to

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Comment: @Tom change Html.BeginForm()
to Html.BeginForm("Request_Insert", "Request", FormMethod.Post)

Comment: Quite strange. I changed the begin form. When I click the button , I can see a postback happening but the it still doesnt hit the controller method.

Comment: I dotn see any error in console view of developer tools of the browser

Comment: I just cleared my cookies and refreshed the browser and it works now

Comment: My only question is I know you have recommeded to shift the buttons into request header view as per my design but from the visual aspect I wanted the buttons on main view that is outside all the partial views on that page and yet trigger the controller method. How do I achieve that